# Is <span> inside <h1> the same as just <h1> for search engines?

Tags: html, search-engines, heading

Are search engines still able to recognize the below as `<h1>` text, even with the other tags inside?

```
<h1><span>App</span>Strap<span>.</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines don't care about SPAN tag and do not need it. They give value to the text of a `<h1>` as it suggests heading of the content or importance of the content in the `<h1>` tag. But `<span>` doesn't play any role in the SEO.

Comment: That sounds right to me, but do you have a reference for that by chance?

Comment: @AndrewLott , SPAN is styling html tag and used for  CSS styling purposes. So  we can logically conclude that it doesn't matters in SEO .